# How to sum across rows with all NAs to be 0/NA

Tags: r, dplyr, data-wrangling

I have a dataframe:

```
dat <- data.frame(X1 = c(0, NA, NA),
                  X2 = c(1, NA, NA),
                  X3 = c(1, NA, NA),
                  Y1 = c(1, NA, NA),
                  Y2 = c(NA, NA, NA),
                  Y3 = c(0, NA, NA))
```

I want to create a composite score for X and Y variables. This is what I have so far:

```
clean_dat <- dat %>% rowwise() %>% mutate(X = sum(c(X1, X2, X3), na.rm = T),
                                          Y = sum(c(Y1, Y2, Y3), na.rm = T))
```

However, I want the composite score for the rows with all `NA`s (i.e. rows 2 and 3) to be 0 in the column `X` and `Y`. Does anyone know how to do this?

Edit: I'd like to know how I can make `X` and `Y` in rows 2 and 3 `NA` too.

Thanks so much!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default, `sum` or `rowSums` return 0 when we use `na.rm = TRUE` and when all the elements are `NA`.  To prevent this either use an `if/else` or `case_when` approach i.e. determine whether there are any non-NA elements with `if_any`, then take the `rowSums` of the concerned columns within `case_when` (by default the `TRUE` will return `NA`)

```
library(dplyr)
dat %>% 
  mutate(X = case_when(if_any(starts_with('X'), complete.cases) 
    ~ rowSums(across(starts_with('X')), na.rm = TRUE)),
   Y = case_when(if_any(starts_with('Y'), complete.cases) ~ 
    rowSums(across(starts_with('Y')), na.rm = TRUE)) )
```

-output

```
  X1 X2 X3 Y1 Y2 Y3  X  Y
1  0  1  1  1 NA  0  2  1
2 NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA
3 NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA
```

Comment: Thanks! I'm hoping the value for Y in row 1 will be 1 instead of 0 (i.e. ignoring the NA in Y2). Everything else is correct. Is that possible?

Comment: @jo_ sorry, there was a typo.  I closed the bracket early

Comment: thank you! And how do I make X and Y `NA` in rows 2 and 3?

Comment: @jo_ is this a new change in your post

Comment: yes! I am curious how it'll look like if it was `NA` instead of `0` for `Y` in rows 2 and 3. Sorry if that was confusing. I can make a separate post if that's better.

Comment: I applied your solution to a bigger dataset with more columns. An error that comes up is that '`X` must be a vector, not a `formula` object'. I checked that I copied your solution correctly. Do you know what might have gone wrong? I can try simulating the bigger dataset if that's helpful.

Comment: @jo_ I assume that you have some other columns with names that starts with 'X' and is not numeric.  In that case you can specify the column names as such i.e. `if_any(c(X1, X2, X3), complete.cases)` and `across(c(X1, X2, X3))`  Similarly for `Y` columns

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/244783/discussion-between-jo-and-akrun).